# "Well-known classical phrase"

Tags: phrase-request

What is the "well-known classical phrase"? *All Quiet On The Western Front*

> Himmelstoss is a raging book of army regulations. The Kaiser couldn't be more insulted. "Tjaden, I command you, as your superior officer: Stand up!" "Anything else you would like?" asks Tjaden. "Will you obey my order or not. Tjaden replies, without knowing it, in **the well-known classical phrase**.

Comment: If nothing is said afterwards (specifying what is the classical phrase), I'd think it's just a common and traditional response, like "Ein Befehl ist ein Befehl" ("an order is an order"), or "At your command, Sir!". I think your question here isn't what the phrase "the well-known classical phrase" means in English, but rather what is the classical phrase being used by Tjaden. The problem is that this would require the reader to know more about the book context and this phrase is probably German anyway

Comment: @flen
A quick google search finds the answer to what the phrase is, see my answer.

Comment: This isn't a ELL question.  The meaning is clear,  you need a [literature.se] analysis.

Comment: This seems to be mistranscribed. For example, the last quotation mark never closes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exact question was asked, and answered, with multiple sources cited, in [this Literature.SE thread](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11696/what-well-known-phrase-from-g%C3%B6tz-von-berlichingen-is-alluded-to-in-all-quiet-i) to be exact.

That thread says (in an answer by user [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku) dated 4 Match 2020 in the link above) the answer is:

> The most famous phrase from Goethe's play *Götz von Berlichingen* and goes on to say:
>
> The most famous phrase from Goethe's play Götz von Berlichingen is     > > er kann mich im Arsche lecken!

> This is taken from the third act, when Götz von Berlichingen's castle is being besieged and a herald comes to tell him it were better to surrender. This leads to a response that made the play famous:
>
> > Mich ergeben! Auf Gnad und Ungnad! Mit wem redet Ihr! Bin ich ein Räuber! Sag deinem Hauptmann: Vor Ihro Kaiserliche Majestät hab ich, wie immer, schuldigen Respekt. Er aber, sag's ihm, er kann mich im Arsche lecken!
> > [Schmeißt das Fenster zu.]

> Translation ([1885, hosted by The Online Library of Liberty](http://files.libertyfund.org/files/2113/Goethe_0841-03_EBk_v6.0.pdf)):

> > Surrender—surrender at discretion. With whom speak you? Am I a robber? Tell your captain, that for the emperor I entertain, as I have ever done, all due respect; but as for him, he may lick my arse!
> > [Shuts the window with violence.]

Probably only the last phrase is intended here.

One might note that in the [version I found online](http://www.fiatlux-day.org/e2a/literature/all_quiet/all_quiet-10.html), the passage (which is from chapter 10) reads:

> We put on extraordinary airs, every man treats the other as his valet, bounces him and gives him orders. "There is something itching under my foot; Kropp my man, catch that louse at once," says Leer, poking out his leg at him like a ballet girl, and Albert drags him up the stairs by the foot. "Tjaden!" – "What?" – "Stand at ease, Tjaden; and what's more, don't say 'What,' say 'Yes, Sir,' – now: Tjaden!" Tjaden retorts in the well-known phrase from Goethe's *Gotz von Berlichingen*, with which he is always free.

I suspect this is from a different translation from the German original than the one quoted in the question.